# GoogleCloudPlatform explainable_ai_sdk.load_model_from_ai_platform error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I want to deploy and use a model on AI platform prediction with AI explanations.
So I created a model version :

**code :**

```
    PROJECT_ID = 'gcloudtest-318713'
    MODEL = 'flowers' + TIMESTAMP
    REGION = 'us-west1'
    IG_VERSION = 'v_ig_3'
    
    ! gcloud beta ai-platform versions create $IG_VERSION --region=$REGION \
    --model $MODEL \
    --origin $export_path \
    --runtime-version 2.2 \
    --framework TENSORFLOW \
    --python-version 3.7 \
    --machine-type n1-standard-4 \
    --explanation-method integrated-gradients \
    --num-integral-steps 25 \
    --region $REGION
```

**results :**

```
Using endpoint [https://us-west1-ml.googleapis.com/]

Explanations reflect patterns in your model, but don't necessarily reveal fundamental relationships about your data population. See https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/ai-explanations/limitations for more information.

Creating version (this might take a few minutes)......done.
```

And I checked the status of my model deployment, and the model is deployed correctly.

**code :**

```
# Make sure the IG model deployed correctly. State should be `READY` in the following log
! gcloud ai-platform versions describe $IG_VERSION --model $MODEL --region $REGION
```

**results :**

```
Using endpoint [https://us-west1-ml.googleapis.com/]

createTime: '2021-07-08T08:01:06Z'

deploymentUri: gs://explanablebucket/explanations/mymodel

etag: TPD5G-pd3BE=

explanationConfig:
  integratedGradientsAttribution:
    numIntegralSteps: 25

framework: TENSORFLOW

machineType: n1-standard-4

name: projects/gcloudtest-318713/models/flowers20210708062102/versions/v_ig_3

pythonVersion: '3.7'

runtimeVersion: '2.2'

state: READY
```

and I tried to load model from ai platform. But it failed with below error.

**code :**

```
remote_ig_model = explainable_ai_sdk.load_model_from_ai_platform('gcloudtest-318713', 'flowers20210708062102', 'v_ig_3')
```

**results :**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-cc00f8746ef5> in <module>
----> 1 remote_ig_model = explainable_ai_sdk.load_model_from_ai_platform('gcloudtest-318713', 'flowers20210708062102', 'v_ig_3')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/explainable_ai_sdk/model/model_factory.py in load_model_from_ai_platform(project, model, version, credentials, region, input_modalities)

57   if not input_modalities:
58     input_modalities = utils.create_modality_inputs_map_from_metadata(
59         utils.fetch_explanation_metadata(model_endpoint_uri, credentials))
60 
61   return _MODEL_REGISTRY[_CAIP_MODEL_KEY](model_endpoint_uri, credentials,


/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/explainable_ai_sdk/model/utils.py in fetch_explanation_metadata(model_endpoint_uri, credentials)
73   """
74   explanation_md_uri = _extract_explanation_metadata_uri(
75       _get_deployment_uri(model_endpoint_uri, credentials))
76 
77   return explain_metadata.ExplainMetadata.from_file(explanation_md_uri)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/explainable_ai_sdk/model/utils.py in _get_deployment_uri(model_endpoint_uri, credentials)
29   """
30   response = http_utils.make_get_request_to_ai_platform(model_endpoint_uri,
31                                                         credentials)
32 
33   if 'deploymentUri' not in response:

ValueError: Target URI https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/gcloudtest-318713/models/flowers20210708062102/versions/v_ig_3 returns HTTP 404 error.
Please check if the project, model, and version names are given correctly.
```

I can't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem. my model is deployed to specified region but the sdk seems to search another region. code :

```
remote_ig_model = explainable_ai_sdk.load_model_from_ai_platform(project = 'gcloudtest-318713', mode = 'flowers20210708062102', version = 'v_ig_3', region = REGION)
```